# Inno Setup disable Browse button CreateInputDirPage

Tags: inno-setup, disabled-control, pascalscript

I need to disable browse button in an new `CreateInputDirPage`.

Code:

```pascal
DataDirPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir,
    'Select DB', '¿Folder?',
    'Select Folder',
    False, '');
DataDirPage.Add('');
```

Function `NextButtonClick`:

```pascal
if (CurPageID = 6) then
    DataDirPage.DirBrowseButton.Enable := False;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TInputDirWizardPage.Buttons` property to access the *Browse* buttons:

```pascal
DataDirPage.Buttons[0].Enabled := False;
```

See [Support Classes Reference](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses).

---

*Do not hard-code page IDs, use `wpSelectDir` instead of `6`.*